# LaTeX: Rule as float environment

Tags: floats, environments, rules

I try to use rules as float, using `float.sty` to create a new typ of float, but within the new definde environment I can't use `\linewidth`, since the usage results in the missing number error. Does someone know how to fix this problem?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}

 \newfloat{rule}{H}{rule}[section]
 \floatname{rule}{Rule}

\begin{document}

\begin{rule}
 \rule{linewidth}{10cm} 
 \caption{Float 3}

 }\end{rule}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Use another name, eg `Rule`. Internally the `\newfloat` defines `\rule` and `\endrule` which overwrites the old `\rule` command

Comment: I apologize for any orthographical or grammatical mistakes, I made.

Comment: A `\caption` for a rule? Really? ;-)

Comment: Wasn't my idea, but thanks for the fast and helpful answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\rule` is already defined as the classical `\rule` command, so the float environment name `rule` must conflict with `\rule`.

What does go wrong actually?

Let's assume `\newfloat{rule}{...}{...}` as was done in the OP.

- Using `\rule{linewidth}{10cm}` inside of `\begin{rule}...\end{rule}` will fail since there is a nested environment without `\endrule`
- Using `\rule{\linewidth}{10cm}` will fail because `\linewidth` is now a length macro not further interpreted and it will give the

  > ! Missing number, treated as
  >   zero.

  error.
  'Correcting' it with `\the\linewidth` is of no use, since the missing `\endrule` statement will cause another error.

**Solution**: use a different name, say `myrule` for the float environment.

There is also a wrong `}` just before `\end{rule}` and it must read `\rule{\linewidth}{10cm}`, i.e. the length macro must be specified explicitly with the `\` - character.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}

\newfloat{myrule}{H}{rule}[section]
\floatname{myrule}{Rule}

\begin{document}

\begin{myrule}
\rule{\linewidth}{10cm} 
  \caption{Float 3}
\end{myrule}


\end{document}
```